# error to run an emulator in my flutter project

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'A:\visualcodeflutter\learning_codepur\new flutter learning\flutter_application_1\android\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Build completed with 1 failures.
> org/jetbrains/kotlin/config/LanguageVersion

how to run flutter emulator in visual studio

Comment: Please add more details . Run `flutter doctor -v` in terminal and copy/paste result in your question.